# eclipse GGTS 4.3 and grails 2.3.5 - debugger cant connect second time round

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, debugging, grails

Working on work laptop with Mcfee firewall and policies - but not using internet on corporate VPN. General mail, browser, etc. are working fine.

1. download GGTS 4.3 - or Eclipse Kepler build and add via marketplace
2. add grails 2.3.5
3. create grails project
4. create domain class  - edit the spock unit test so it runs and add a break point in the test
5. debugAs the unit test - debugger fires and i can connect - let the test complete
6. re rerun the debugAs - grails gets lost and debugger cant connect - on this or any other project - running the unit test seems to set a global condition in eclipse. Have to restart eclipse to get the debugger to work.

Also fails if RunAs - run as works - but debugger won't connect afterwards.

If I add an ordinary script and break point (don't ever run a unit test), then the debugger works fine each time.

What could be the cause of this?